# python Directory structure display of comma delimited string based on open and closed parentheses

Tags: python, tree, hierarchy

I am learning python. This is my first stackoverflow question too and struggling with formatting the output to show my requirement.
I am writing python code for converting a string with comma delimited values into a level hierarchy display data like the following.

```
s = "(id,cb,e(id,fn,eT(id), ln),lc)"
```

I want a output like this

```
-id
-cb
-e
  --id
  --fn
  --eT
    ---id
  --ln
-lc
```

so far I have done some coding, but I am struggling to refine it.

```
class parent-child():
     stack = []
     def tree_recur(self,employee, level):
    s = s[s.index("(")+1:s.rindex(")")]
    ind = 0
    while(s.rstrip != null or s != ""):
            ss = s.index(",")
        words = s[ind:ss]
        parenind = words.index("(") 
        if parenind == -1:
            stack.append(level,words)
            s = s[ss+1:len(s)]
        else:
            stack.append(s[ss+1:parenind-1])
            closeparenind = s.index(")")
            ss1= s[parenind:closeparenind]
            return tree_recur(self,ss1,level+1)

    def main():
        s = "(id,created,employee(id,firstname,employeeType(id), lastname),location)"
        level = 0
        print(E = parent-child(s, level))

    main()
```

can someone help me with refining this code. I don't know how to print "-" before string depending on how deep the level. That is level 1 one hyphen, level 2 two hyphens, level 3 three hyphens and move up a level when is parentheses is closed. I would like to thank for your help and time spent on helping me.

Comment: Please put all of your code in a code block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already trying to parse. The simpler way would be to iterate through each character.

```
s = "(id,cb,e(id,fn,eT(id), ln),lc)"

hyphens = 0
result = []
current = ""

for c in s:
    if c == "(": hyphens += 1
    if c == ")": hyphens -= 1

    if c.isalnum():
        if not current:
            current += "-" * hyphens
        current += c
    elif current:
        result.append(current)
        current = ""

result = " ".join(result)

print(result)
```

Which prints:

```
-id -cb -e --id --fn --eT ---id --ln -lc
```

**Edit:**

I can understand you want it in this format:

```
-id
-cb
-e
  --id
  --fn
  --eT
    ---id
  --ln
-lc
```

This can be done so by changing:

```
current += " " * 2 * (hyphens - 1) + "-" * hyphens
```

and

```
result = "\n".join(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and simple code. Thank you for introducing isalnum().

Comment: I am wonder how to sort alphabetically by levels. How to count the number of hyphens before words and sort alphabetically. I am trying to wrap around how to do it but not able to come up with anything. Thank you for your help and time.